# How can i keep the case when I am using select and paste to C-s input field?

Tags: copy-paste, isearch, case-folding

I see a word in buffer1. I want to look for it in buffer2.  I select the word in buffer1. I select buffer2 as my current buffer, hit `C-s`, and press `mouse-2` (the middle mouse button).

Emacs converts the word to lowercase, and I can't find it...  The word has both lower and upper cases in it. How can I prevent Emacs from downcasing the search pattern?

I am using Emacs version 23.1.1 on RHEL 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant configuration option is `search-upper-case`.

As with many things, you can find this information in Emacs itself. For example, use `C-h r` to open the Emacs manual, and use `i` to search the index for `isearch`. This leads to the Incremental Search topic, which includes a section on Isearch Yank with this:

> Normally, when the search is case-insensitive, text yanked into the
>   search string is converted to lower case, so that the search remains
>   case-insensitive.  However, if the
>   value of the variable ‘search-upper-case’  is other than ‘not-yanks’, that disables this down-casing.

The next logical step would be to check the documentation for the variable mentioned (`C-h v search-upper-case`):

> If non-nil, upper case chars disable case fold searching.
>   That is, upper and lower case chars must match exactly.
>   This applies no matter where the chars come from, but does not
>   apply to chars in regexps that are prefixed with `\`.
>   If this value is `not-yanks`, text yanked into the search string
>   in Isearch mode is always downcased.

You can customize it using `M-x customize-option search-upper-case`.
You can also just set it in your init file:

```
(setq search-upper-case t)
```

Comment: Thanks.
I did look for online help, but not in the emacs itself. Well, I will do my best not to repeat that mistake.